# How to save the time when user logs out?(closed)

Tags: php, laravel

I use `Laravel 5.8` authentication and authorization. 
I have an 'Admin' who manages Companies and Workers. 
When Admin login i want to show what new companies and users was
 created since last admin session. For that i thought to store in
 database time when Admin's session finished and query from database
 all Companies and Workers what was created since last session.
 If Admin use `logout` i can store time in database, but how to
 store time if Admin just close tab ??

*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

I created middleware to save time from last request:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            $id = Auth::id();
            Admin::whereId($id)->update(['last_enter' => now("Europe/Moscow")]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest recording the last request the user made rather than when they closed the tab. If nothing else, they could have loaded the page, opened a new tab and started browsing somewhere else and then just closed your app's tab after an hour or so but they've not actually seen anything that's happened since the initial load. You could even take it one step further and record the times for different route requests.

Comment: That have sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to archieve this only using laravel I would suggest you to check `middlewares`. You can have a middleware where are requests will pass through so last request for you mean that that's the last time user has used it.

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware) you can learn more about middleware in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking anecdotally, you can use [`sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) with the [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) event to send a request. I had to use it to capture the amount of time a user spent watching a video and if they closed the tab I needed to record it, this method worked consistently for me.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
    navigator.sendBeacon('your-url',
      JSON.stringify({})
    );
}, false);
```

**Alternatively**, you could in those instances where the user closes the window set the logout time to the session timeout time, for example: `sign-in-time + session-timeout-time = logout-time`, but again, that isn't "accurate".

Comment: I would like to use Laravel only for it.

Comment: @Loctarogar that just would not be possible, Laravel is server side and has only executed when the page finishes its load, you need something to listen for that specific event.

Comment: @Loctarogar that can be done even from laravel side. You can have middleware to check request done so last request for you mean that that's the last time user has used it. Also be aware that using the provided method here there are a lot situations where it doesn't work.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the session is still active when the request is sent so you should be fine.

Comment: How so? If you leave the tab open for about an hour, let it sit there and then close it. Then the session won't still be active (unless you've changed the timeout, that is).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wait, are you asking regarding the alternative method?

Comment: Nah. I was thinking of the `sendBeacon()`-method. If that doesn't get triggered until the tab closes, then there should be a risk that the session have timed out.

Comment: @EdisonBiba i've done as you suggested. I created middleware and save last request time. You may create answer, i'll accept it as correct.

Comment: @Loctarogar that's great. I am happy that I was a help here. I also created it as an answer